# HortonWorks Sandbox HDP gets stuck

Tags: virtualbox, hortonworks-sandbox

installing HortonWorks Sandbox HDP on virtualbox in windows 10 home machine freezes my system.

RAM = 8 GB.

virtualization is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I understood what was the problem,
minimum requirement for HDP_2.5_virtualbox.ova is **8GB RAM**,
my system had 8GB RAM, so all the memory was allocated to the **VM**,
so my Host Machine stuck.

Comment: see this for reference https://hortonworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Import_on_Vbox_5_11_2015.pdf